# 500 internal server error when sending % sign through post request glassfish

Tags: web-services, glassfish, jax-rs, internal-server-error

I have web service hosted on glassfish server. which basically translates English world to Hindi word.
suppose I post a request like close I get निकट in response but when I post a request something like 100 % off I get 
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error as a response

My glassfish server failed to handle % sign.
what should I do to overcome this error? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwuuT.png)

Comment: You should post the stacktrace in the question, check your server log.

Comment: thnaks macros for your help

Comment: i got my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use %25 for % because the percent ("%") character serves as the indicator for percent-encoded octets in Glasfish, it must be percent-encoded as "%25" for that octet to be used as data within a URI. For more information, refer link below :

http://urlencoder.urlencode.in/url/decoder/character-encoding-glassfish-url-encode